# Firestore Missing or insufficient permissions after set new rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote some code that works perfectly with the default rules. The code is this:

```
function listenerNewMessages(chats) {

        chats.forEach(function(item) {

            db.collection("pm").doc(chats[0]).collection('messaggi')
            .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
                snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
                    if (change.type === "added" && change.doc.data().idUser != idUser && (String(Date.now()) > change.doc.id  && dateChat < change.doc.id) && idChat != item) {

                        //alert('hai ricevuto un nuovo messaggio in '+ item)
                        $('#contact-'+item).removeClass('flash')

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#contact-'+item).addClass('flash')
                        }, 50);
                    }
                })

            })
        })
    }
```

But if I use these rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /pm/{pm} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.partecipanti.partecipante1 || request.auth.uid == resource.data.partecipanti.partecipante2;
    }

  }
}
```

I get

```
Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't delete and repost the same question. It can result in a question ban. https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Is not the same question

Comment: Instead edit the original question (if it has no answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `request.resource` qualifier for new writes.

`allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.some-property-A || request.auth.uid == resource.data.some-property-A;`

`allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.some-property-B || request.auth.uid == resource.data.some-property-B;`

Comment: i've added these two lines with correct property but the result not change, the problem is not "new writes"... the problem is detect new writes from other users

Comment: can u add a pic of your database, with `pm` expanded and the last 4 digits of your `auth.currentUser.uid`?